# How to strip down paths in package.xml via file-tag?

Tags: php, pear

Im trying to simplify my `package.xml` file, because it contains many of this

```
<phprelease>
    <filelist>
        <install as="path/to/my/Class.php" name="classes/path/to/my/Class.php" />
        <!-- Many more of this -->
    </filelist>
</phprelease>
```

According the [Manual](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/guide.users.concepts.filerole.php), it should be possible, to strip relative paths by using the `baseinstalldir`-attribute, but its either (a kind of) ignored, or leads to curious pathnames. For example

```
<dir name="/">
  <dir name="classes">
    <file baseinstalldir="/path/to/my" name="path/to/my/Class.php" role="php" />
  </dir>
</dir>
```

installs the file into `path/to/my/classes/path/to/my/Class.php`, that is obvious crap.

Does anyone knows a solution to strip one folder from the path, that does not require a big bunch of `install-as`-elements?

Update:

It seems, that the pear packager rewrites `package.xml`, before it puts it into the package. One of the steps it performs is, that it flattens the `contents`-section.

```
<dir name="/">
  <dir name="classes">
    <file baseinstalldir="/path/to/my" name="path/to/my/Class.php" role="php" />
  </dir>
</dir>
```

becomes

```
<dir name="/">
  <file baseinstalldir="/path/to/my" name="classses/path/to/my/Class.php" role="php" />
</dir>
```

The installer resolve this to `path/to/my/classes/path/to/my/Class.php` of course...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PEAR does not support what you want (that is, `package.xml` v2.0).

[Pyrus](http://pear2.php.net/PEAR2_Pyrus) supports `package.xml` **v2.1** which behaves exactly as you expect it.